# Check existence of a password by using try catch

Tags: c#

I know that using try catch is not appreciated by many developers and not by myself, especially when it comes to parsing or checking a certain value.

In the code I have, if some exception happens is that it is good (so true), otherwise it is not good (false).

My request is not to recode this, but just explain to me if this a good practice or not.

```
private bool HasPassword(string filePath)
        {
            bool hasPassword = false;
            try
            {
                var stream = IoWrapper.OpenStreamRead(filePath);
                PDF.Document document = new PDF.Document(stream);
            }
            catch (PDF.WrongPasswordException)
            {
                hasPassword = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var erroMessage = string.Format("Error while accessing '{0}' file", filePath);
                Log.Error(erroMessage, e);
                MessengerInstance.Notify(erroMessage, NoteLevel.Error);
            }

            return hasPassword;
        }
```

Comment: There is not enough code here to provide you with an answer. For example, you could be using `HasPassword` to provide different error messages when accessing a file by username and password - that could be an enumeration risk and isn't a good practice. You'll need to add more detail or more code for better answers.

Comment: It is all about try catch usage to check wether a value exists or not

Comment: Well, it's not generally considered good practice but without knowing the API of your other objects no one can suggest improvements beyond style points but you've already said you don't want that. If there is no other choice from the API of `PDF.Document` then good practice or not, **you have no choice**.

Comment: yes, i don't have a lot of choices

Comment: Is there really no other API for checking whether the file is password protected? What library do you use?

Comment: @t3chb0t  Yes there is an Open Source solution (PdfSharp) but I do not have time. yet the question is precisely what is good practice to use the Tray catch you check

Comment: You already know that such a design should be avoided but if there is no other way then there is no other way and you need to live with it ;-] especially if you have no time to look for a more appropriate API which I cannot believe because you have plenty of time for asking questions and answering to comments ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t It's just a little bit different when a solution takes two or three days, so I'm not over five minutes to reply to a comment. but I take your advice

Comment: We can start the code review with margin left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream implements iDisposable
Should be in a `using` or `dispose` in a `finally`

If Document implements iDisposable then ditto

Capture IO errors separate

```
catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Format to the same left margin

Don't care if you only care about try catch
This is code review - post clean code

The try catch will work just fine after you clean up other code problems
It is logical to throw an exception if the file cannot be opened

**If there is no method IsFilePasswordProtected it is fine to use the exception**

You are also not checking for File.Exists and I think that is fine.  If you are pretty sure the file exists then it is cheaper just to catch it in an exception. An exception is not *that* expensive.

But your code has other problems

```
private bool? HasPassword(string filePath)
{
    bool? hasPassword = false;
    Stream stream;
    PDF.Document document;
    try
    {
        stream = IoWrapper.OpenStreamRead(filePath);
        document = new PDF.Document(stream);
    }
    catch (PDF.WrongPasswordException)
    {
        hasPassword = true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        var erroMessage = string.Format("Error while accessing '{0}' file", filePath);
        Log.Error(erroMessage, e);
        MessengerInstance.Notify(erroMessage, NoteLevel.Error);
        hasPassword = null;
    }
    // let a general exception just be thrown
    finally
    {
        if(document is IDisposable) ((IDisposable)document).Dispose();
        if(stream is IDisposable) ((IDisposable)stream).Dispose();
    }
    return hasPassword;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could use some formatting :-P

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> catch (PDF.WrongPasswordException)
> {
>       hasPassword = true;
> }
> ```

This looks like the exception is essentially doing flow control. This is a bad use of exceptions.

Exceptions are for unexpected, usually unrecoverable errors. The way exception handling works is intended for exiting gracefully from such an error without having the application just blow up. Exceptions are also computationally expensive.

---

> ```
> try
> {
>      var stream = IoWrapper.OpenStreamRead(filePath);
>      PDF.Document document = new PDF.Document(stream);
> }
> catch (PDF.WrongPasswordException)
> {
>     hasPassword = true;
> }
> catch (Exception e)
> { ...
> ```

Catching specific exceptions is good. But this code is not catching any of the exceptions that opening/reading a stream may cause.

Catching a specific exception is good because there is context to capture specific information relevant to *that* exception type; which can really help troubleshooting.

---

> ```
> try
> {
>      var stream = IoWrapper.OpenStreamRead(filePath);
>      PDF.Document document = new PDF.Document(stream);
> }
> ```

This would be better...

> ```
> try
> {
>      var stream = IoWrapper.OpenStreamRead(filePath);
> } catch { ... }
> try
> {
>      PDF.Document document = new PDF.Document(stream);
> } catch { ... }
> ```

This goes to the idea of catching specific exceptions. Here, each `catch` can be specific to the exceptions thrown by stream and then PDF.Document. And the "gaps" between the multiple try/catch blocks gives the code flexibility for recovering from the 1st try and then execute the next block.

The general rule, make narrowly scoped try blocks.

Comment: You assume there is another way to determine if the file is password protected.

Comment: Code would not work.  Stream would be out of scope in the second try.  There is an IOException class.

Answer (score 1):

I would let PDF.WrongPasswordException (because you don't have a choise) be the only exception to catch in this method, because all other exceptions have nothing to do with its Purpose (to check for password). If the file it self is missing or invalid, then you really can't tell if the file has a password or not and therefore returning false doesn't give the client valid information. If the IO exception instead is left to the client to respond to, he can react appropriately.

```
private bool HasPassword(string filePath)
        {
            bool hasPassword = false;
            try
            {
                var stream = IoWrapper.OpenStreamRead(filePath);
                PDF.Document document = new PDF.Document(stream);
                // OBS: I think you should set hasPassword = true here
                hasPassword = true;
            }
            catch (PDF.WrongPasswordException)
            {
                hasPassword = true;
            }

            return hasPassword;
        }
```

or maybe:

```
private bool HasPassword(string filePath)
        {
            bool hasPassword = false;
            try
            {
                var stream = IoWrapper.OpenStreamRead(filePath);
                PDF.Document document = new PDF.Document(stream);
            }
            catch (PDF.WrongPasswordException)
            {
                hasPassword = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var erroMessage = string.Format("Error while accessing '{0}' file", filePath);
                Log.Error(erroMessage, e);
                MessengerInstance.Notify(erroMessage, NoteLevel.Error);
throw e;
            }

            return hasPassword;
        }
```

Comment: Don't agree.   This is probably being used in a loop.  Code is logging the error and moving on.

Comment: @Paparazzi: OK, but then the purpose of the method is not just to check if the document has a password but to check if it (the document) is valid at all, and should be named accordingly - in my opinion :-)

Comment: Still don't agree but not worth discussing.